# abi.encode() in Python

Tags: solidity, brownie

I am working with brownie and I need to find a way to do what `abi.encode()` does in Python. Here is a contract:

```
function fundSubscription(address _linkAddress,bytes calldata _data) {
   // _data needs to be encoded. 
}
```

The data argument needs to be encoded when we call this function from python script. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `convert` from brownie and use `convert.to_bytes(_data)` from Python script. Here is full [link](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-convert.html).